# Javascript image arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I have found this [javascript plugin](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/) that puts images into a responsive grid which will expand a large view of the image on click (like google images). I want to modify the structure of the large view to display multiple images instead of one large image.

Is there a way I change this code so that the largesrc attribute is not just a link to a single image but an array of images?

html;

```
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com" data-largesrc="img/example.jpg" data-title="Example Title" data-description="Example Description">
      <img src="img/example.jpg">
    </a>  

    <div class="og-expander">
      <div class="og-expander-inner">
        <span class="og-close"></span>
        <div class="og-fullimg">
          <div class="og-loading"></div>                      
        <img src="img/example.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>       
      <div class="og-details">
        <h3>Example Heading</h3>
        <p>Example Description</p>
        <a href="http://example.com">Visit website</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

js;

```
// update preview's content
var $itemEl = this.$item.children('a'),
    eldata = {
        href: $itemEl.attr('href'),
        largesrc: $itemEl.data('largesrc'),
        title: $itemEl.data('title'),
        description: $itemEl.data('description')
    };
```

Comment: what do you mean by multiple images? Do you want them to appear where the description appears? This plugin has a very specific use-case in mind, so you may have to do some modifications to the source code.

Comment: plese post your html code.. without that it cannot be solved

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your plugin will do that or not but looks like there are a couple of lightbox plugin which can do this.

http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/12174/lightbox-with-multiple-images/p1